# Eclipse managed bean binding on pages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Neither Ctrl+click nor Ctrl+space works for beans on pages, i.e. i can't go into bean from page just moving mouse on its name and pressing Ctrl+click, and i don't get content assist when typing some element's value using bean value. All this perfectly works in eclipse 3.5, but not in eclipse 3.7, neither in JSP editor nor in HTML editor. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You might need a plugin for do so. Take a look at what plugins are you starting in `Preferences -> general -> startup and shutdown` and compare with 3.5.

If you find that a missing plugin is needed install it. You can do so (depending on the version) by  `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace`.

Your plugins are `Help -> Install new software -> in this screen there is a link to "What is already installed"`

Comment: Well, yes, there's plugin in old eclipse that most probably deals with this ("JavaServer Faces Tools - Core"), but i don't know how to include it in startup list of new eclipse. It's in the list of installed plugins of new eclipse but it just doesn't appear in "Startup and Shutdown" list and there's no "Add" button or something.

Comment: Needed plugin is installed. It's included as standard plugin of "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". But it's not in "Startup and Shutdown" list and i don't know how to add it there.

Answer (score 0):

For me I did the following and it worked:

1. Right Click on project -> properties
2. Go to Project Facets [image]
3. Click on "convert to faceted form"
4. Check in Java, Dynamic Web Module and Java Server Faces in my case I put it Version 1.8[image]
5. For Java Server Faces, click on Further Configuration Required -> and choose the proper for your case.
   [image]
6. Apply and close.